# Suppose det(A) = 0, show that there exists a nonzero square matrix B such that AB = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Suppose det(A) = 0, show that there exists a nonzero square matrix B such that AB = 0.

I know that A must be singular given that det(A) = 0, but how do I go on and finish the proof?

Comment: Hint: $ker(A)$ is non-trivial.

Comment: try to proceed by contradiction or contrapositive.

Comment: Let $B= \operatorname{adj} A$. Look up the formula for a matrix inverse.

Answer (score 0):

$\det(A)=0$. Hence the matrix is singular and the columns are linearly dependent: $a_1\vec c_1+...+a_n\vec c_n=0$ where $a_i$ are numbers, not all $0$, $\vec c_i$ are columns. Let $B$ be the matrix where the first column is $(a_1,...,a_n)$, the other columns are $0$. Then $B\ne 0$ but $AB=0$.